# Button added by TamperMonkey Script shows only briefly

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey, reddit

I love Reddit. I use the new layout, not the old one. There are TamperMonkey "add-on" scripts that allow you to do things like hide posts, color comments differently, etc. but the majority of them only work on the old layout. And then there is the "Reddit Enhancement Suite", it does some thins but not what I want. I modified a script that I found and can't get it to work.
I want to have a button to add all links to the browser's history, essentially marking it as visited, which makes Reddit think you read the post.

The "button" shows briefly but then disappears, can anyone help out with the TamperMonkey script below?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Reddit "Mark All Read"
// @namespace     http://userscripts.org/users/mb34
// @description   Adds a button next to the logo to Mark All Posts Read
// @include       http://reddit.com/*
// @include       http://*.reddit.com/*
// @include       https://www.reddit.com/
// @include       https://www.reddit.com/*
// @include       https://*.reddit.com/*
// @exclude       http://www.reddit.com/comscore-iframe/*
// @exclude       http://static.reddit.com/ads/*
// @version       1.0
// @date          8/2/2018
// @creator       MrBaseball77
// @homepage
// @grant GM_addStyle   
// ==/UserScript==

//debugger;
var code_string = "(" + function() {

    var item;
    //helper funciton
    function xpath(p, context) {
        if(!context) context = document;
        var i, arr = [], xpr = document.evaluate(p, context, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
        for(i = 0; item = xpr.snapshotItem(i); i++) {
            arr.push(item);
        }
        return arr;
    }

    //grab button at top of page
    var button = xpath("//div[@class='s1f7qvlr-5 hkOTKM']")[0];
    if(typeof button=="undefined"||!button) return;

    //create button with hide all functionality
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hide All");
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.appendChild(textnode);
    span.setAttribute('style', 'color: #0079D3;');
    btn.setAttribute('class','etmkug-14 SuUwW');
    btn.setAttribute('style','margin-left:10px;padding:3px;border:1px solid #0079D3;border-radius:2px;');
    btn.setAttribute('id','reddit-mark-all-read');
    btn.appendChild(span);
    button.parentElement.parentElement.appendChild(btn);
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        //ajax loading spinner
        var spinner = {
            lock : 0,
            remove : function(){
                --spinner.lock;
                if(spinner.lock ==0) {
                    var element = document.getElementById('reddit-mark-all-read');
                    element.style.background = "#EFF7FF";
                }
            },
            add : function(){
                //created ajax spinner with http://www.ajaxload.info/ #EFF7FF and #FF4500 (orangered)
                //created data uri with http://www.sveinbjorn.org/dataurlmaker
                var element = document.getElementById('reddit-mark-all-read');
                element.style.background = 'url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAO/3//9FAPLMwv'+
                'pzQv9FAPiJYvafgvWqkiH+GkNyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBhamF4bG9hZC5pbmZvACH5BAAKAAAAIf8LTkVUU0NBUEUyLjADAQAAACw'+
                'AAAAAEAAQAAADMwi63P4wyklrE2MIOggZnAdOmGYJRbExwroUmcG2LmDEwnHQLVsYOd2mBzkYDAdKa+dIAAAh+QQACgABACwA'+
                'AAAAEAAQAAADNAi63P5OjCEgG4QMu7DmikRxQlFUYDEZIGBMRVsaqHwctXXf7WEYB4Ag1xjihkMZsiUkKhIAIfkEAAoAAgAsA'+
                'AAAABAAEAAAAzYIujIjK8pByJDMlFYvBoVjHA70GU7xSUJhmKtwHPAKzLO9HMaoKwJZ7Rf8AYPDDzKpZBqfvwQAIfkEAAoAAw'+
                'AsAAAAABAAEAAAAzMIumIlK8oyhpHsnFZfhYumCYUhDAQxRIdhHBGqRoKw0R8DYlJd8z0fMDgsGo/IpHI5TAAAIfkEAAoABAA'+
                'sAAAAABAAEAAAAzIIunInK0rnZBTwGPNMgQwmdsNgXGJUlIWEuR5oWUIpz8pAEAMe6TwfwyYsGo/IpFKSAAAh+QQACgAFACwA'+
                'AAAAEAAQAAADMwi6IMKQORfjdOe82p4wGccc4CEuQradylesojEMBgsUc2G7sDX3lQGBMLAJibufbSlKAAAh+QQACgAGACwAA'+
                'AAAEAAQAAADMgi63P7wCRHZnFVdmgHu2nFwlWCI3WGc3TSWhUFGxTAUkGCbtgENBMJAEJsxgMLWzpEAACH5BAAKAAcALAAAAA'+
                'AQABAAAAMyCLrc/jDKSatlQtScKdceCAjDII7HcQ4EMTCpyrCuUBjCYRgHVtqlAiB1YhiCnlsRkAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA==") '+
                '#EFF7FF no-repeat center';
            }
        }; // spinner definition

        //grab & "visit" all
        var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-click-id='body']");
        var count = 0;

        for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            //add spinner background image
            spinner.add();
            //**********************************************************************
            // use replaceState to push a new entry into the browser's history, essentially
            // telling the browser that you visited the link, marking it as read!!
            //**********************************************************************
            history.replaceState({},"",links[i]);
            ++count;
        } // for
        //******************************************
        // Do I need to remove the background here??
        //******************************************
        // spinner.remove();
        if(count===0){
            alert('None Found.');
        } // if

        // stop default click action
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    }); // btn.addEventListener

} + ")()";

// workaround for Google Chrome
// I realize this is NOT the nice way to do such things but from what I
// read there's no other way to access Reddit's native JS code
// (maybe one day 'hiding' will be added to the API)
var script = document.createElement('script');
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.appendChild( document.createTextNode( code_string ) );
document.body.appendChild(script);
```

Here's how it looks now:

[image]

Here's where I want the button to go:

[image]

Comment: Are they updating the UI dynamically so it redraws?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: At first, it worked, then I added the removal of the spinner, `spinner.remove();`, and thought that was the cause. Now it just won't show, even without the spinner removal.

Comment: Did you figure out why it is removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you. Took liberty to edit your code.

1. Insert the whole snippet inside a immediately executing function with a setTimeout.
2. Get the last `button` using `querySelectorAll`.
3. Insert the element using `insertAdjacentElement`.
4. Don't insert spinner inside the for loop. Insert it before starting the loop.

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name          Reddit "Mark All Read"
// @namespace     http://userscripts.org/users/mb34
// @description   Adds a button next to the logo to Mark All Posts Read
// @include       http://reddit.com/*
// @include       http://*.reddit.com/*
// @include       https://www.reddit.com/
// @include       https://www.reddit.com/*
// @include       https://*.reddit.com/*
// @exclude       http://www.reddit.com/comscore-iframe/*
// @exclude       http://static.reddit.com/ads/*
// @version       1.0
// @date          8/2/2018
// @creator       MrBaseball77
// @homepage
// @grant GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
setTimeout(function(){
    var item;
    var button = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("div.s1f7qvlr-5.hkOTKM")).pop();

    if(typeof button=="undefined"||!button) return;

    //create button with hide all functionality
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    var textnode = document.createTextNode("Hide All");
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.appendChild(textnode);
    span.setAttribute('style', 'color: #0079D3;');
    btn.setAttribute('class','etmkug-14 SuUwW');
    btn.setAttribute('style','margin-left:10px;padding:3px;border:1px solid #0079D3;border-radius:2px;');
    btn.setAttribute('id','reddit-mark-all-read');
    btn.appendChild(span);
    button.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend",btn);

    var element = document.getElementById('reddit-mark-all-read');
    var spinner = {
            lock : 0,
            remove : function(){
                if(spinner.lock ==0) {
                    element.style.background = "#EFF7FF";
                }
            },
            add : function(){
                //created ajax spinner with http://www.ajaxload.info/ #EFF7FF and #FF4500 (orangered)
                //created data uri with http://www.sveinbjorn.org/dataurlmaker
                element.style.background = 'url("data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPIAAO/3//9FAPLMwv'+
                'pzQv9FAPiJYvafgvWqkiH+GkNyZWF0ZWQgd2l0aCBhamF4bG9hZC5pbmZvACH5BAAKAAAAIf8LTkVUU0NBUEUyLjADAQAAACw'+
                'AAAAAEAAQAAADMwi63P4wyklrE2MIOggZnAdOmGYJRbExwroUmcG2LmDEwnHQLVsYOd2mBzkYDAdKa+dIAAAh+QQACgABACwA'+
                'AAAAEAAQAAADNAi63P5OjCEgG4QMu7DmikRxQlFUYDEZIGBMRVsaqHwctXXf7WEYB4Ag1xjihkMZsiUkKhIAIfkEAAoAAgAsA'+
                'AAAABAAEAAAAzYIujIjK8pByJDMlFYvBoVjHA70GU7xSUJhmKtwHPAKzLO9HMaoKwJZ7Rf8AYPDDzKpZBqfvwQAIfkEAAoAAw'+
                'AsAAAAABAAEAAAAzMIumIlK8oyhpHsnFZfhYumCYUhDAQxRIdhHBGqRoKw0R8DYlJd8z0fMDgsGo/IpHI5TAAAIfkEAAoABAA'+
                'sAAAAABAAEAAAAzIIunInK0rnZBTwGPNMgQwmdsNgXGJUlIWEuR5oWUIpz8pAEAMe6TwfwyYsGo/IpFKSAAAh+QQACgAFACwA'+
                'AAAAEAAQAAADMwi6IMKQORfjdOe82p4wGccc4CEuQradylesojEMBgsUc2G7sDX3lQGBMLAJibufbSlKAAAh+QQACgAGACwAA'+
                'AAAEAAQAAADMgi63P7wCRHZnFVdmgHu2nFwlWCI3WGc3TSWhUFGxTAUkGCbtgENBMJAEJsxgMLWzpEAACH5BAAKAAcALAAAAA'+
                'AQABAAAAMyCLrc/jDKSatlQtScKdceCAjDII7HcQ4EMTCpyrCuUBjCYRgHVtqlAiB1YhiCnlsRkAAAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA==") '+
                '#EFF7FF no-repeat center';
            }
        }; // spinner definition
    btn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
        //ajax loading spinner

        //grab & "visit" all
        var links = document.querySelectorAll("a[data-click-id='body']");
        var count = 0;
        spinner.add();
        for(var i=0; i<links.length; i++) {
            //add spinner background image
            //**********************************************************************
            // use replaceState to push a new entry into the browser's history, essentially
            // telling the browser that you visited the link, marking it as read!!
            //**********************************************************************
            history.replaceState({},"",links[i]);
            ++count;
        } // for
        //******************************************
        // Do I need to remove the background here??
        //******************************************
        spinner.remove();
        if(count===0){
            alert('None Found.');
        }
        event.stopPropagation();
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    },1000);
})();
```

Comment: A couple of issues. 1. It sets the URL in the address bar to the last link in the list. 2. Would it be possible to put it between the subreddit selector and the search input in the header bar? I couldn't get it in there. I first had to resize the edit width to 90% and then tried to insert it before the `<form>` that contains the edit. Just didn't really work. I will try doing that with your code.

Comment: Fixed #1 by saving the current location: `var location = window.location.href;` and then setting the window.location after the loop: `window.location = location;`.   Still can't get the thing in the header bar, though and it only does around 50 links, wonder why?

Comment: Adding the timer helps. Not sure what is removing the element